Conditional jolt for null empty not present in the input request
The Jolt transformation should handle cases where the request data may be null, empty, or not present. It should transform the data to the desired output based on the conditions specified in the Jolt specification. These conditions are based on the source property and hqAddress, isInternal properties.
Can you help here to know the problem and share the any materials around to learn more about jolt.
Input.json - example 1
{
  "id": "testId",
  "basicInfo": {
    "hqAddress": "N",
    "source": "NIT",
    "accountNumber": "123",
    "isInternal": true
  }
}

ActualJolt.json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "envId",
      "basicInfo": {
        "source": {
          "SIT": {
            "hqAddress": {
              "P": {
                "#P-SIT": "system.env"
              },
               //if not P anything else or if hqAddress empty or not present in the request should be N-SIT
              "*": {
                "#N-SIT": "system.env"
              }
            }
          },
          "UAT": {
            "hqAddress": {
              "P": {
                "#P-UAT": "system.env"
              },
                //if not P anything else or if hqAddress empty or not present in the request should be N-UAT
              "*": {
                "#N-UAT": "system.env"
              }
            }
          },
          "*": {
            "@isInternal": {
              "true": {
                "#true": ["isInternalAccount", "isDevAccount"]
              },
              //if not true anything else or if isInteranl empty or not present in the request should be false
              "*": {
                "#false": ["isInternalAccount", "isDevAccount"]
              }
            }
          },
          "hqAddress": {
            "P": {
              "#P": "system.env"
            },
            //if not P anything else or if hqAddress empty or not present in the request should be Other
            "*": {
              "#Other": "system.env"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

]


ExpectedOutput.json
{
  "envId" : "testId",
  "isInternalAccount":false,
  "isDevAccount":false,
  "system":{
     "env":"Other"
   } 
}


You can start with converting "isInternal" key to "@2,isInternal" and "hqAddress" key at the bottom to "@1,hqAddress" in order to be correctly address their level within the tree respectively.
The ~ operator might be used within a modify spec to check existence and nullability as the github document for v0.0.22 states.
Lastly, a boolean conversion may be needed based on the expected result which show boolean ones while the conversion might produce stringified types of them .
As a result, you can convert yours to this one :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "envId",
      "basicInfo": {
        "source": {
          "SIT": {
            "hqAddress": {
              "P": {
                "#P-SIT": "system.env"
              },
              "*": {
                "#N-SIT": "system.env"
              }
            }
          },
          "UAT": {
            "hqAddress": {
              "P": {
                "#P-UAT": "system.env"
              },
              "*": {
                "#N-UAT": "system.env"
              }
            }
          },
          "*": {
            "@2,isInternal": {
              "true": {
                "#true": ["isInternalAccount", "isDevAccount"]
              },
              "*": {
                "#false": ["isInternalAccount", "isDevAccount"]
              }
            }
          },
          "@1,hqAddress": {
            "P": {
              "#P": "system.env"
            },
            "*": {
              "#Other": "system.env"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "~isInternalAccount": false,
      "~isDevAccount": false,
      "~system": {
        "~env": "Other"
      }
    }
  },
  { // boolean results expected
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "isInternalAccount|isDevAccount": "=toBoolean"
    }
  }
]

